# Jetpack navigation: Title and back/up arrow in the action bar?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have installed the latest canary version of Android Studio, and followed this (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) instruction to implement a simple two page navigation. Basically page1 has a button, and when it is clicked, the app shows page2.

It works, but there is one problem... It does not seem to do anything with the action bar automatically. Is it supposed to show up/back arrow and the "Label" attribute on the action bar automatically by the navigation library? Or am I supposed to do all the work manually as before? I want to show the back arrow and "Details" on action(tool) bar when page2 is showing.

On button click at page 1.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    button1.setOnClickListener {
        val nav = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
        nav.navigate(R.id.show_page2)
    }
}
```

Main activity XML. By default it was the default Action Bar, I have replaced it with a ToolBar. There was no difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Nav graph XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
            app:startDestination="@id/page1">

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity2"
        android:name="com.android.navtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="activity_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/page1"
        android:name="com.android.navtest.BlankFragment2"
        android:label="Home page"
        tools:layout="@layout/page1">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/show_page2"
            app:destination="@id/page2"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/anim1"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/anim2"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/page2"
        android:name="com.android.navtest.BlankFragment"
        android:label="Details"
        tools:layout="@layout/page2"/>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can connect your ActionBar to a NavController using [`NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#setupActionBarWithNavController(android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)). This is generally done in your Activity, right after you call `setSupportActionBar()`:

```
supportActionBar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)

// Get the NavController for your NavHostFragment
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

// Set up the ActionBar to stay in sync with the NavController
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
```

This approach is covered in the [Navigation talk at Google I/O 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GCXtCjtg40&t=821).

Comment: I saw examples that used it, but I thought it was about using the bottom navigation, as you see, my main activity does not have a bottom navigation. The examples on the linked video and your code do not show the full source. It is called somewhere in the activity? But the activity does not have `setupActionBarWithNavController`. I could not find any full source code example for this.

Comment: There are multiple setup methods, one for the action bar, one for bottom nav, one for side nav, etc. If you only want to use the action bar one, only call that one. The code in the video is the entirety of the activity's `onCreate` method.

Comment: Yes it had the entire `onCreate`, but in my case the compiler does not resolve `setupActionBarWithNavController`. So, I thought there must be something more to be done with the activity like inheriting something other than `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Did you include the `navigation-ui-ktx` dependency as per the [adding components page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#navigation)?

Comment: When I created a new project and added nav graph, Android Studio asked me if I want it to add dependencies, so I thought it automatically did it for me. I just checked it and it only had added `navigation-fragment`, not `navigation-ui`. So, I manually added it and now it works.

Comment: How can you keep the hamburger menu on going back to the root? It dissappears with this approach. I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: @A.Steenbergen - the [navigation drawer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) details how you'd want to use an `AppBarConfiguration` to handle the hamburger menu.

Comment: There's a compilation error: **too many arguments for NavController androidx.navigation.fragment**

Comment: @ianhanniballake hey can you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182885/android-jetpack-navigation-component-condtional-navigation-issue). I am having up/back button sync problem.

Comment: This will not work if you have a BottomNavigationView or you have Gate/Splash screen before a main page.

Comment: I don't think this code works anymore. When I try it, I get "Activity does not have a NavController set" in the console.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to have navigation back button hidden in more than one place (default is only for home fragment) you can add ids of fragments to AppBarConfiguration and pass this as second parameter of setupActionBarWithNavController, for example:

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.splashFragment, R.id.onboardingFragment, R.id.homeFragment))

setupActionBarWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.nav_host), appBarConfiguration)
```

Comment: that was exactly what i wanted.. I dont want back/up arrow key .. and setOf is the right answer

Comment: What if you have both ActionBar and BottomNavigationView?  This won't work

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have done.

 `onSupportNavigateUp` is called when the user navigates up and it set again.
 by calling this `setupActionBarWithNavController` tell android to update the title of toolbar.

`navigateUp` Handles the Up button by delegating its behavior to the given NavController. This should generally be called from AppCompatActivity.onSupportNavigateUp().

```
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityGameConfigBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_game_config)
        supportActionBar?.show()

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, null)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.graph)
            .build()

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
    }
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

my solution with binding - the code is in MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity)
    navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)//needs to be after binding
    toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph))
}
```

as for the titles - first I removed labels (android:label) from the fragments in navigation graph (label overwrites title from what I've tested)

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/productListFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ProductListFragment"
        android:label="TO_BE_REMOVED"
        tools:layout="@layout/product_list_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_productListFragment_to_mainMenuFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainMenuFragment" />
    </fragment>
```

each fragment sets the title and subtitle in `onResume`, here example from ProductListFragment

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val actionBar = (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar
    actionBar?.title = getString(R.string.product_list_title)
    actionBar?.subtitle = getString(R.string.product_list_subtitle)
}
```