# Android Jetpack Navigation component Condtional navigation issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I was trying to add conditional navigation following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional). But I ran into a problem.
So the steps I followed are:

1. Created `navigation drawer` in the `MainActivity` with `HomeFragment` as a start destination.
2. Conditionally navigated to `FromBlackFragment` from `BlankFragment`.
3. Want to go to `HomeFragment` from `FromBlackFragment` by clicking `up/back button`.

The problem is with **step 3** above. I am going back to `HomeFragment` by clicking `back button` **whereas I am navigated to `BlankFragment` on `up button` click**. The code for **step 3** is: (inside **FromBlackFragment.java** file)

```
requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                    @Override
                    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                        Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack(R.id.homeFragment, false);
                    }
                });
```

The **MainActivity.java** file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NavController navController;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navController = findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
                        .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout).build();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**BlankFragment.java** file:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences sp = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("Testing",0);
        if(!sp.getBoolean("b",false)){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("b",true);
            editor.apply();
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.fromBlackFragment);
        }
    }
```

**FromBlackFragment.java** file:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_from_black, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                    @Override
                    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                        Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack(R.id.homeFragment, false);
                    }
                });
    }
```

**Note**: Shared preferences used in the code is not part of the problem.

Please help. Thanks.

**Edit:** (More specifically the question is) How to sync **upNavigation** and **back button**?

Answer (score 0):

Step1:  In MainActivity's `onCreate`, you need to call [setSupportActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up)(toolbar);

Step2: Call [setupActionBarWithNavController](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupActionBarWithNavController(androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity,%20androidx.navigation.NavController,%20androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration))() from NavigationUI, passing in the proper arguments, this will:

> Set up the ActionBar returned by
>   AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar() for use with a NavController.

Step3: By calling setupActionBarWithNavController(), you should now override [onSupportNavigateUp](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar)(), putting in the call to navigate:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

If NavigationUI.navigateUp won't get you to home fragment destination, you maybe want call a Navigation method that explicitly get you there.

Comment: It gets me to the **HomeFragment on BackButton click** but not on **upNavigation** it means that they are not synced. So do you know how to sync them? Your solution above didn't solve the issue.